# Show a piece of text only when mouseover a certain region

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to show a `outputText` component only when the mouse is over a `panel` region. How can I achieve that ?

I tried using `show()` & `hide()` js functions with `onmouseover` event on `panel` but failed to achieve results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly

```
<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#something").mouseover(function (){
          $("#myText").show();
        })
         $("#something").mouseout(function (){
          $("#myText").hide();
        }
     )}
     );
```

And your Panel

```
  <p:panel id="something" >
          <h:outputText id="myText" styleClass="hidden" value="hi i am hidden when is mouse is somewhere"/>
       </p:panel>
```